# What does the "+" sign mean when it comes to ranking in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, data-science

```
SELECT
a.*
,b.*
FROM
(SELECT b.s ,b.C ,b.score
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sc a WHERE a.c='01'AND a.score>b.score)+1 mc
FROM sc b  WHERE b.c='01' HAVING mc BETWEEN 2 AND 3
```

What does the +1 mean? The query is trying to rank the 2nd best and 3rd best students and their grades of each course.

Thanks

Comment: It adds 1 to (SELECT COUNT(*)...b.score)

Comment: Does this query even run smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

Its just the addition operator (plus)

So it adds 1 to the result returned by the subquery. It works because your subquery is **always** returning a single integer as it is a COUNT(*) without GROUP BY

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sc a WHERE a.c='01'AND a.score>b.score)
```

If the subquery retruns a count of 0, your `mc` column will be 0+1=1

Additionally your query is malformed: you have a `HAVING` clause without a `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: how a.score>b.score works? Both "a" and "b" are "sc", im trying to get the students with 2nd and 3rd highest scores.

How does it count the number?

Comment: and how can it compare the "score"s to "score" itself when the course is same